# UITableViewCell subclass needs to play sound when selected

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a UITableViewCell subclass that appears in several tables in my app, and I want it to play a sound effect when selected. I know how to play the sound (I'm already doing it for buttons) but I need to know how to respond to the touch event of a table cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/setSelected%3aanimated%3a) method (override it in your uitableviewcell subclass).

then in your subclass:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
   if (selected) {
       //TODO: play your sound here
   }
}
```

Cheers, 
Pawel

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the table view delegate
2. implement the method - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and play your sound in this method.

Comment: So this can't be accomplished in the cell itself? It has to be done in the tableviewcontroller?

Comment: Ahh sorry, now i understand why you would want to do it on the cell. You might be able to override the setSelected method in the cell